# Second monitor is not working after freshUbuntu 22.04 installation

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg

My computer has an NVIDIA 3080 Ti graphics card. I have just installed Ubuntu 22.04. When using the Nvidia drivers, my second monitor is detected but it's just a black screen. Switching to the Xorg drivers gives me an image on the other screen, but I can only run it @ 120hz and not 165hz, and it seems really choppy.

Answer (score 4):

Check what driver is being used.

If it says that there is a custom driver being used, open a terminal of your choice and run:

`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`.

Once completed, reboot by either selecting the Reboot option in the GNOME power menu or run `reboot` in the terminal.

Comment: This didn't work for me! Started the first time after the driver installation but when I restarted, it didn't recognize me again.

Comment: This worked well for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

One of the cables to the monitor works in only one port and the other cable works in both ports. Switching the two DisplayPort cables around and changing which port they were plugged into in the graphics card fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I have a newly setup of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and the second monitor (in addition to the laptop display) did not work after connecting the HDMI cable. As suggested above, I did drivers auto-install as suggested above. Unfortunately, that did not resolve the issue. What worked for me is to change the refresh rate as shown below:

[image: display setting - refresh rate]

Answer (score 1):

You have to change refreshing the screen. for example from 60hz to 59,94hz in ubuntu screen settings. It worked for me

Comment: I had only two options to select, 48 or 60 Hz. This didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I just converted over from 18.04 > 20.04 > 22.04.  I tested out some updated software on 20.04, and it worked really well (including my second screen), so I move immediately to 22.04.

Now, on 22.04, my second screen does not work, which brought me here.

Symptoms:

- Ubuntu knows it is there as it shows in settings.
- The mouse pointer shows up on that screen but otherwise stays dark.
- I can even drag a software window over to it, but the screen remains dark.
- I installed the proprietary driver and then the second screen was ignored and did show on the settings, so I went back to the Open Source driver.
- The Ubuntu splash comes up on the second monitor during boot.
- Mirroring screens only messes with the settings of the larger primary monitor.

Tests to try:

- disconnect the primary monitor to see what happens.
- This has a dual connected video cards with four connectors so I thought of switching where the displays are plugged in; plug them both into the same physical card.

With my dual joined gaming card setup I had them plugged into separate cards.
When I disconnected the primary display - it booted but 22.04 wouldn't talk to the secondary display (no sign on screen).

So I plugged the secondary into the same card as the primary display (and repowered the primary display) and then everything worked. I might try removing the jumper between the two video cards and see it the secondary display will work plugged into a the other card.

Interesting that my monitor set up worked with both 18.04 and 20.04.

So look at how you have your monitors plugged into your video cards especially if it is card"S".

Answer (score 0):

for me switching from Wayland to Xorg solved a lot of issues. When removing the second monitor the screen of the laptop became blank, after set Xorg no problem arose.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, switching resolution from 3840x1080 with 200% scale (automatically selected) to 5120x1440 with 100% scale was the trick. It was flickering and noisy on the screen until reboot.